# Looking for improvement to a procedure to determine a sorted array's median

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

Function parameters are the sorted array and the length of the array. The goal is to determine the median of an odd or even length array.

Odd length arrays are handled simply by determining the exact middle element, even length arrays are handled by getting the two elements that "straddle" the midpoint and averaging them.

The question is: (after the `even_:` label) I had to repetitively determine the left and right of the straddle values in the manner that you see.

At the line `mov eax, [edi+eax-4]`, I can manipulate this with differing multiples of 4 and get any index position value I want.  However, if I immediately follow the instruction `mov eax, [edi+eax-4]` with `mov esi, [edi+eax +/- any multiple of 4]`, I always get "0" (esi arbitrarily selected).

So, is the way I did it the best way or am I lacking some wisdom on how to access two array elements in one go, so to speak?

```
GetMedian   PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp+12]           ; eax = length of array.
    mov ebx, 2
    cdq
    div ebx                     ; eax = Length of array/2.
    cmp edx,0
    je even_                    ; Jump to average the straddle.
    mov ebx, TYPE DWORD
    mul ebx                     ; eax now contains our target index.
    mov edi, [ebp+8]
    mov eax, [edi+eax]          ; Access array[eax].
    jmp toTheEnd
even_:
    mov ebx, TYPE DWORD
    mul ebx                     ; eax now contains our target index.
    mov edi, [ebp+8]            ; edi now contains @array[0].
    mov eax, [edi+eax-4]        ; Dereferences array[left] so a value is in eax.
    mov esi, eax                ; save eax (value left of straddle).
    mov eax, [ebp+12]           ; eax = length of array.
    mov ebx, 2
    cdq
    div ebx
    mov ebx, TYPE DWORD
    mul ebx                     ; eax now contains our target index.
    mov edi, [ebp+8]
    mov eax, [edi+eax]          ; Access array[right] (value right of straddle).
    add eax, esi                ; list[eax-1] + list[eax].
    mov ebx, 2
    cdq
    div ebx
toTheEnd:
    pop ebp
    ret 12
GetMedian ENDP
```

Comment: Have you considered writing the code in a higher-level language that compiles to assembly and checking the code a compiler would generate? Your code is breathtakingly convoluted and inefficient in comparison to anything an optimizing compiler will produce.

Comment: @EOF yep, and the reason for the post. No. I'm good at C and C++ but not sure how to do exactly that (just yet), but if I can generate a listing file for this program would I be able to potentially glean improvements?

Comment: You don't have to divide by 2 that way, you can just right shift. (particularly easy here since length is presumably unsigned)

Comment: @Chris: You can get gcc and clang to emit assembly by setting the command-line switch `-S`. If you don't have either of those compiers, take a visit to gcc.godbolt.org.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about improving or optimizing working code. It is more suitable for [codereview.se].

Comment: Besides the fact that you should never use `div` to divide by powers of 2 (shift instead), use `cdq` and `idiv` on signed numbers, or `xor edx,edx` and `div` on unsigned numbers.  `cdq` + `div` doesn't make sense, other than to save a byte of code with inputs known to be below 2^31.  (e.g. for [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78972/30206).

Comment: @KenWhite: You could read the question as being "how do I calculate a median in x86 asm".  The fact that the sample implementation works is nice, because we don't have to spend time debugging it, but it's not super relevant.  The main reason for writing things in asm is high performance.  Even the author suspects this code is not really a suitable solution to the problem.  So you could easily look at it as a "what I've tried so far" like in many questions.  I think you can argue that the code doesn't solve the problem / isn't "working", because it's too slow / bloated.

Comment: @PeterCordes: No; it is *working*, albeit slowly or bloated. I can read the question exactly as asked, which is *looking for improvement for working code*, which is exactly the reason CR exists - peer review of working code for the purpose of improving or optimizing it.

Comment: @KenWhite: that's fair.  The way this one is worded is very much code-review style.  What I should have said is that it could have been on-topic here if it had been asked differently.  There are lots of questions like "how can I do XYZ with SSE intrinsics, like this naive scalar code but faster".  There's a lot of x86 performance / asm optimization stuff on SO already, but maybe it would be good to have some on codereview.SE, too.  I've gone looking for asm code to review over there, and found extremely thin pickings.

Comment: @PeterCordes: A lot of the existing questions were posted before CR existed, just like a lot of general computer related questions were posted before [su]. Now that the other sites are available, questions that properly belong on those sites should be directed there.

Comment: @KenWhite: Agreed; it's the same deal with Unix shell script questions scattered across unix.SE, SO, SuperUser, and AskUbuntu.SE.  I'm somewhat sympathetic to this question, though, because a good answer will throw away almost all of the OP's code.  Also, it turns out it had at least two bugs.  (And unless I'm mistaken about the `ret 12`, breaking the caller's stack pointer should have been detected with testing by any caller that returned instead of calling `exit()`.  Still, I guess codereview is still the right place to ask if you think your code is right, even if your test missed bugs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW, your code doesn't actually work:  `mov ebx, 2` clobbers ebx, but you don't save/restore it.  So you've stepped on a register that is call-preserved in all the usual ABIs / calling conventions.  See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

Also, I think `ret 12` should be `ret 8`, since you take two 4 byte args.  (See below).

---

Here's an interesting idea: branchless by always adding two elements.  For an odd-length array, it's the same two elements.  For an even-length array, it's the middle-round-down and middle-round-up.

If your code actually has the same array length repeatedly, so a branch will predict well, a conditional branch  will probably be better (on `test ecx, 1` / `jnz odd`, or `jc` after shift).  Esp. if odd lengths are the common case.  *Sometimes* it's worth doing something unconditionally, even if it's not always needed.

```
; Untested
GetMedian   PROC
    ;; return in eax.  clobbers: ecx, edx (which don't need to be saved/restored)
    mov   ecx, [esp+8]            ; ecx = unsigned len
    mov   edx, [esp+4]            ; edx = int *arr
    shr   ecx                     ; ecx = len/2.  CF = the bit shifted out. 0 means even, 1 means odd

    mov   eax, [edx + ecx*4]      ; eax = arr[len/2]
    sbb   ecx, -1                 ; ecx += 1 - CF.  
    add   eax, [edx + ecx*4]      ; eax += arr[len/2 + len&1]

    shr   eax, 1                  ; eax /= 2  (or sar for arithmetic shift)
    ret 12    ;;; Probably a bug
GetMedian ENDP
;; 5 instructions, plus loading args from the stack, and the ret.
```

I left off the instructions to make a stack frame, because this is a leaf function with no need for any local storage.  Using `ebp` doesn't make anything easier or help with backtraces, and is a waste of instructions.

For most conditions, you have to use `setcc` to get a 0 or 1 in a register based on the flag.  But `CF` is special.  add-with-carry and sub-with-borrow use it (which I take advantage of here), and so do the rotate-through-carry instructions.  It's more common to `adc  reg, 0`, but I needed the inverse, and came up with `sbb  reg, -1` to add 0 or 1 depending on CF.

**Are you sure `ret 12` is right**?  Your 2 args are only 8 bytes.  `ret imm16` adds the immediate to `esp` *after* popping the return address, so the count is the total change to the stack pointer due to the `call`/`ret` pair.

Also, I assume that adding two elements won't wrap (carry or overflow), even when it's the middle element of an odd-length array.

---

Or, another branchless approach which is probably worse

```
; Untested
; using cmov on two loads, instead of sbb to make the 2nd load address dependent on CF
GetMedian   PROC
    mov   ecx, [esp+8]            ; ecx = unsigned len
    mov   edx, [esp+4]            ; edx = int *arr
    shr   ecx, 1                  ; ecx = len/2.  CF = the bit shifted out. 0 means even, 1 means odd

    mov   eax, [edx + ecx*4]      ; eax = arr[len/2]
    mov   edx, [edx + ecx*4 + 4]  ; edx = arr[len/2+1]  (reads past the end if len=0, and potentially touches a different cache line than len/2)
    cmovc edx, eax                ; CF still set from shr.  edx = odd ? arr[len/2] : edx

    add   eax, edx
    shr   eax, 1                  ; eax /= 2  (or sar for arithmetic shift)
    ret 8
GetMedian ENDP
```

---

### Branching implementation:

This is probably more like what you'd get from a C compiler, but some compiler might not be smart enough to branch on CF as set by the shift.  I wouldn't be surprised either way, though; I think I've seen gcc or clang branch on flags set by shifts.

```
; Untested
GetMedian   PROC
    ;; return in eax.  clobbers: ecx, edx (which don't need to be saved/restored)
    mov   ecx, [esp+8]            ; ecx = unsigned len
    mov   edx, [esp+4]            ; edx = int *arr
    shr   ecx                     ; ecx = len/2.  CF = the bit shifted out. 0 means even, 1 means odd

    mov   eax, [edx + ecx*4]      ; eax = arr[len/2]

    jc   @@odd   ; conditionally skip the add and shift
    add   eax, [edx + ecx*4 + 4]  ; eax += arr[len/2 + 1]

    shr   eax, 1                  ; eax /= 2  (or sar for arithmetic shift)
@@odd:  ;; MASM local label, doesn't show up in the object file
    ret 8
GetMedian ENDP
```

Alternatively:

```
    jnc   @@even
    ret   8         ; fast-path for the odd case
@@even:  ;; MASM local label, doesn't show up in the object file
    add   eax, [edx + ecx*4 + 4]  ; eax += arr[len/2 + len&1]

    shr   eax, 1                  ; eax /= 2  (or sar for arithmetic shift)
    ret 8   ; duplicate whole epilogue here: any pop or whatever
```

---

### Play with the scale factor instead of shifting:

Mask off the low bit of `len`, and then use `arr[len/2] = [edx + (len/2)*4] = [edx + len*2]`

This shortens the dependency chain from `len` to result by one `shr`, but it means the first load has to come after the branch.  (And without tail-duplication (separate `ret`s), we'd need an unconditional branch somewhere to implement the `if(odd){}else{}` structure instead of the simpler `load; if(even){}; ret` structure.)

```
; Untested
GetMedian   PROC
    ;; return in eax.  clobbers: ecx, edx (which don't need to be saved/restored)
    mov   ecx, [esp+8]            ; ecx = unsigned len
    mov   edx, [esp+4]            ; edx = int *arr
    test  ecx, 1
    jz   @@even
    mov   eax, [edx + ecx*2 - 2]  ; odd
    ret   8
@@even:
    mov   eax, [edx + ecx*2]
    add   eax, [edx + ecx*2 + 4]
    shr   eax, 1
    ret 8
GetMedian ENDP
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Its elegance is eclipsed by only its efficiency.  ...and yes, ret 8, my bad.